# remove duplicate STL vector in STL vector

Tags: c++

I have a STL vector of STL vector  which contains integer values. Some inside vectors are duplicating but their element order is not the same. Now, I want to get a vector of vector without having any duplicate inner vectors. I've been seen the following method:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVec;
std::sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end());
myVec.erase(std::unique(myVec.begin(), myVec.end()), myVec.end());
```

the problem is that i want to eleminate duplicates keeping the order of elements of each order(original order or without sort it), what is the best way to do this? is there another way more efficient?

Example:

```
1 6 4 5
3 1 5 2----> result of elimination: 1 6 4 5
2 1 3 5                             3 1 5 2
```

Thanks in advance

vacing

Comment: I don't understand your example, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: What he's showing in the example is that because `3 1 5 2` and `2 1 3 5` contain the same values, just not in the same order, they're considered duplicates and thus removed.

Comment: In that case, the method posted is incorrect since it does not sort the inner vectors.

Comment: Unless the less than operator for `vector<int>` has been overloaded.

Comment: excuse me I've made a mistake, I've edited the example. In that case option 1 of devil is good for me, thanks any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not exactly clear. So I am going to give two answers.

(1) If you wish to remove duplicates but retaining 1 copy while maintaining `myVec`'s order, you need to use a set.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > myVec;
//or std::unordered_set if you expect mostly unique sorted inner vectors
std::set< std::vector<int> > exists; 
std::vector< std::vector<int> > tmpVec;

for (std::size_t i=0, N=myVec.size(); i<N; ++i)
{
    std::vector<int> key(myVec[i]);
    std::sort(key.begin(), key.end());
    if (exists.find(key) == exists.end())
    {
        exists.insert(key);
        tmpVec.push_back(std::vector<int>());
        std::swap(myVec[i], tmpVec.back());
     }
}

std::swap(tmpVec, myVec);
```

(2) If you wish to remove all elements that appear more than once in `myVec` you need a map of counters.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > myVec;
//or std::unordered_map if you expect mostly unique sorted inner vectors
std::map< std::vector<int>, unsigned > counters; 

// first loop to count
for (std::size_t i=0, N=myVec.size(); i<N; ++i)
{
    std::vector<int> key(myVec[i]);
    std::sort(key.begin(), key.end());
    ++counters[key];
}

// second loop to filter
std::vector< std::vector<int> > tmpVec;
for (std::size_t i=0, N=myVec.size(); i<N; ++i)
{
    std::vector<int> key(myVec[i]);
    std::sort(key.begin(), key.end());
    if (counters[key] == 1)
    {
        tmpVec.push_back(std::vector<int>());
        std::swap(myVec[i], tmpVec.back());
     }
}

std::swap(tmpVec, myVec);
```

Both solutions respects the order of elements in `myVec` and retains the original order in the inner vectors' elements.

Comment: Almost, but from the example, it seems like the poster doesn't want to include items that have duplicates at all (whereas you're filtering out the extraneous copies).

Comment: `unordered_map` won't work for `vector<int>` as key.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is enter each vector into a list that's in a map that's keyed by the sorted values of the vector and then iterate through the map choosing ones whose vector `.size()` is 1.

Your map will look something like this:

```
map<vector<int>, vector<vector<int> > > m;
```

Inserting is as follows:

```
m[/*sorted inner_vector*/].push_back(inner_vector);
```

Note that the `inner_vector` that gets pushed maintains its original order.

Comment: excuse me I've made a mistake, I've edited the example. In that case option 1 of devil is good for me, thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

This one here will alert the user, if a `int` already exist within the vector:

```
    using namespace std;
    int num, prev; 

    cout << "Number: "; cin >> num;

            vec.push_back(num);
            sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
            for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size()-1; ++i)
            {
                prev = vec[i];
                if (prev == num)
                {
                    cout << "Duplicated\n"; // or whatever.
                    vec.erase(vec.begin() + i); // Delete the duplicated value.
                }
            }
```